# How can I publish text-based games on python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-based

I'm neither programming very long nor doing it as job. Because I'm doing whatever I want I mostly programm videogames in python 3.7. My newest one is similar to a text-adventure, so it's text based.

But when I want to play it, I'm doing this with the python-IDLE. But if I want to share or even publish my game, you have to have python installed to play it.

Is there any platform or engine I can use?

I really am no insider and never published any code. But I heared you can use batch or unity for those things. How does this work?

Answer (score 2):

If you really don't want any GUI and want to keep it simple, you should consider using an online lightweight python notebook and share the link for that notebook with your audience. This way, your audience won't need to install python on their own system and they can interact with your python code remotely. Take a look at [Replit](https://repl.it/)

You can take it a level up if you want to distribute your game offline. Read: [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

So, technically you want to package and distribute your code.There are many packaging tools available for packaging python code. 
you can go though [this](https://packaging.python.org/) for details.
For